# C++ COM [in, out] safearrays

Tags: c++, qt, com, safearray, qaxobject

I need to call a COM function in C++ that returns a reference to a `SAFEARRAY(BSTR)`.

According to [this document](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaxbase.html#details), it should be:

```
QAxObject object = new QAxObject(...);
QStringList list;

for(int i=0; i<goodSize; i++)
    list << "10.0";

object->dynamicCall("Frequencies(QStringList&)", list);

for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
    qDebug() << list.at(i);
```

but the list elements remain to `10.0`.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

I used Oleview.exe and actually, the function looks like this: `void Frequencies(VARIANT* FrequencyArray);`.

But the documentation of the ActiveX server says: `Use a safearray of strings (VT_BSTR) or reals (VT_R8 for double or VT_R4 for float)`.

Comment: Returns a `SAFEARRAY`, or returns a reference to a `SAFEARRAY`?  COM actually makes that distinction. What does the actual declaration of "Frequencies()" look like in the COM object?

Comment: Returns a reference to a `SAFEARRY`. The prototype is: `Frequencies([in, out] SAFEARRAY(VT_BSTR)*)`.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your `list` variable in a `QList`/`QVariant`, like the linked doc shows in its `SAFEARRAY` in/out example? The doc says: "Note that the QList the object should fill has to be provided as an element in the parameter list of QVariants."

Comment: Any other idea? The function print is `void Frequencies(VARIANT* FrequencyArray);`.

Comment: That is not what you showed earlier. There is a big difference between passing a pointer to a `SAFEARRAY` and passing a pointer to a `VARIANT`. So what is the actual prototype that `Frequencies()` is really using?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. The documentation says `Use a safearray of strings (VT_BSTR) or reals (VT_R8 for double or VT_R4 for float)` but the hardware seems to show the interface `void Frequencies(VARIANT* FrequencyArray);` (seen through Oleview.exe). In fact, if I pass a QVariant or a QList<Variant> to Frequencies it returns `Type Mismatch in Parameter. Pass an array of type string or real.`. If I pass a `QStringList` I have no error but the values are not updated. What could I do? I'm out of idea... :(

Comment: I don't use Qt, so I'm out of ideas. I use ActiveX/COM interfaces directly instead, thus don't suffer from these kind of wrapper issues.

Comment: I found someone with the same issue [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/24201-ActiveQt-QVariant-and-VC-VARIANT?p=246220#post_117128). I think I'm going to do it the same way. But it is a pity Qt doesn't allow to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It was the way to read the results. I had to read the first element of `parameters` then convert it to a `QStringList`. I am angry against me :(

```
IBKDataSet *data = function->FunctionData();
int nbFrequencies = data->dynamicCall("GetNumberOfXAxisEntries()").toInt();
QList<QString> frequencies;
for(int i=0; i<nbFrequencies; i++) {
    frequencies << "0.0";
}
QList<QVariant> parameters;
parameters << QVariant(frequencies);
data->dynamicCall("Frequencies(QList<QString>&)", parameters);
frequencies = parameters.first().toStringList();
for(int j=0; j<frequencies.size(); j++) {
    qDebug() << frequencies.at(j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of the COM object's `Frequencies()` function matches the example in the [document](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaxbase.html#details), except that the example uses `SAFEARRAY(VARIANT)` and your COM object uses `SAFEARRAY(BSTR)` instead.  So try adapting the example code for strings, eg:

```
QList<QString> list;
...
QList<QVariant> parameters;
parameters << QVariant(list);
object->dynamicCall("Frequencies(QList<QString>&)", parameters);
```

Comment: I was thinking to your code. In your example, how do you read the list of strings then? Do you directly read list? Or `for(int i=0; i<parameters.at(0).toStringList().size(); i++) { qDebug() << parameters.at(0).toStringList().at(i); }` ?